# Can't call UI classes with netbeans GUI builder

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

Working on learning the GUI builder for netbeans, and I'm pretty confused. I'm writing a basic LoginUI class with the GUI builder. If I run the class as standalone, the window I want pops up as expected. However if I attempt to create a new instance of it, it does not. My flow of control is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginCntl theLoginCntl = new LoginCntl();
}

public class LoginCntl {

    public LoginCntl(){
        LoginUI theLoginUI = new LoginUI();
}
```

}

```
public LoginUI() {
    initComponents();
    System.out.println("Are we here?");
    //This prints out, so I know the program gets here. The problem is the window does not show up here. 
}

 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new LoginUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

I'm really not sure why I can run it standalone and get the window I want then when I create a new instance of it the window does not appear. I get the feeling I'm missing something pretty basic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Added some more of the generated code that netbeans provides. It does call setVisible(). That being said, while looking for setVisible() I noticed that the GUI builder added

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
```

in some of its generated code. As far as I'm aware you should only ever have 1 main class in a project. Could this be my problem?

Comment: `theLoginUI.setVisible(true)`

Comment: Thanks for the help, setvisible worked. I saw that the builder called setVisible in an exception handler, so I figured it would just take care of that for me. Apparantly it does not. The more you know!

Answer (score 1):

You never Call set visible any where, in fact, it's impossible to determine if your UI actually has a window to be displayed.

If LoginUI extends from something like `JFrame`, the on you should call ...

```
theLoginUI.pack();
theLoginUI.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Actually pack() is already call in `initComponents()`  just `setVisible(true)`, you win me xD by time +1

Comment: @nachokk Assuming that the component extends fro JFrame and NetBeans has been configured to apply pack automatically, but personally, never take the risk ;)